# Differences between a discussion and a disorganized documentation as part of a question

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, voting

Chosen correct answer is not always the best. Sometimes the most voted answers are just the most popular, but not always the most useful or even practical. Good hints or answers can even be found in another comments far away from the most valuable response. So, solution documentation is scrambled even in spite of all reputation restraints.

Comment: What about, no? Why *would* they lead to a discussion?

Comment: No one says that you have to accept the top voted answer... You should always select the answer you find the most useful, regardless of the votes. Votes **can** be useful if you're not certain what the "correct" answer is, which is more likely on some of the more subjective-type sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Chosen correct answer is not always the best.

Your perception of the accept mark is wrong. It doesn't mean it is the correct answer, it means it is the answer the original poster found most helpful.

> Sometimes the most voted answers are just the most popular, but not always the most useful or even practical.

That is why you can keep adding answers to existing questions because over time new insights can lead to better approaches for the same problem.

> <s>Aren't multiple answers for a Stack Exchange's question leading to a discussion?</s>

No, they show to the OP and future visitors that you can have multiple ways to achieve the same goal. Having multiple answers is educational for all users, including the other users that answer. If they find a weak spot in the other answers they either comment or vote so posts can be improved.

Don't under-estimate the power of voting (up and down) as well as leaving comments (once you reached 50 reputation).

In cases where answers (or questions) are really outdated, unfixable or plain dangerous by today's standards a meta post might help to get the attention of the broader community to either vote or delete such posts. Delete voting is a privilege left for [trusted users](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Answer (score 4):

There is no discussion in the most basic SE model, because **answers must not be framed as replies to other answers**. All answers stand alone, or are edited into shape, or are deleted. It's impossible to have a discussion if there's only a question and a choice of answers to pick from, each of which gives its complete argument.

Similarly, **comments are intended primarily to lead to changes in posts**; once they've fulfilled their function, they can be deleted. The classic example is pointing out a bug in an answer, or a better way to do things. Some comments point out unfixable flaws in an answer (or reasons something that appears to be such a flaw is no such thing); these can be useful to direct voting, but ideally would be deleted once the answer is rewritten, clarified, deleted, passed in score by a superior answer, or passes an inferior answer.